# How to fix sound effects in Sonic Adventure 2 using Steam and Playonlinux

Tags: wine, steam, playonlinux

I bought a Humble Sonic Bundle and got a lot of sonic games. I enjoyed playing Sonic Adventure DX but when I tried to play Sonic adventure two after installing the components XACT and dotnet20 from playonlinux the game worked fine ... however there was no sound effects. I reckon it is either something gone wrong in either the program configuration, my computer setup or the games local files. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well I finally solved the problem. It turns out that it doesn't work properly if you install it through playonlinux. To solve this issue, it requires you to install Steam and Sonic Adventure 2 manually with WINE.

!!!WARNING: This tutorial will only work with a WINE version 7.46 or greater!!!

Firstly, open a terminal with `Ctrl + Alt + T` create the wineprefix folder with `mkdir /home/$USER/.local/wineprefixes`and then create a clean WINE prefix with the following command:

```
WINEPREFIX="/home/$USER/.local/share/wineprefixes/[name for the wineprefix]" winecfg
```

This will create your wineprefix and then open the configuration panel for that wineprefix. make sure that Windows Version is set to Windows XP. Close that Window and then run winetricks from start menu. Download the applications dotnet20 and xact (That is the component that gets the sound to work) through *yourwineprefix => install a Windows DLL or Component*. After you have installed each component, click cancel two times to close winetricks. Then you want to install the Steam install package [here](http://cdn.steampowered.com/download/SteamInstall.msi). Next in the termianl cd to the directory containing the file and run:

`env WINEDEBUG="fixme-all" WINEPREFIX="/path/to/your/wineprefix" wine msiexec /i SteamInstall.msi`

Log into your Steam after it has finished updating and install Sonic Adventure 2 normally (you might want to close the terminal running in the backround). From there the game should play normally with the sound effects :).

Notes:
If your computer is any better than my generic Intel then the game should run perfectly. If not then the game would be running in slow motion. I am yet to solve this, and hope that its just my computer.

EDIT: Turns out it may or may not have anything to do with the computer. It turns out that its either a glitch with the FPS or something to do with the graphics card (But why would I need a new graphics card for a game that is 11 years old!). Either way, it is still as slow...

For more information, visit the following links:

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444
https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27139